# Check if accout is activated

Tags: php, oop, pdo

I'm trying to add a way to check if a users account is activated before logging them in. I've added a way to send an email with an activation link and if they click on that link they activate there account. That works, however, when I'm trying to add a way to check if the users account is activated or not in the login class it won't work.

This is the login class:

```
public function login($username = null, $password = null, $remember = false) {

    $validate = new Validate(); 

    if (!$username && !$password && $this->exists()) {
        Session::put($this->_sessionName, $this->data()->id);
    } else {
        $user = $this->find($username);
        if ($user) {
            if ($this->data()->password === Hash::make($password, $this->data()->salt)) {
                if ($this->data()->activated = 1) { 
                    Session::put($this->_sessionName, $this->data()->id);

                    if ($remember) {
                        $hash = Hash::unique();
                        $hashCheck = $this->_db->get('users_session', array('user_id', '=', $this->data()->id));

                        if (!$hashCheck->count()) {
                            $this->_db->insert('users_session', array(
                                'user_id' => $this->data()->id,
                                'hash' => $hash
                            ));
                        } else {
                            $hash = $hashCheck->first()->hash;
                        }

                        Cookie::put($this->_cookieName, $hash, Config::get('remember/cookie_expiry'));

                    }

                } else {
                    $validate->addError('You need to activate your account before you login!');
                }

                return true;

            } else {
                $validate->addError('Invalid password!');
            }

        } else {
            $validate->addError('That username does not exist!');
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

When I use this code ^^ I can login even if the account is activated or not. If I do

```
if ($this->data()->activated == 1) {
```

instead only the activated accounts can login, however, the error messages (You need to activate your account before you login!, Invalid password! etc) dosen't show up and if I try to login using an inactive account I get redirected to index.php but I shouldn't be redirected and errors should pop up. If I do

```
if ($this->data()->activated === 1) {
```

I can't log in with any account even though some are activated and I get redirected to index.php but as said before, once again, I shouldn't be redirected.

In the database I have a field called activated which is an enum with the values 0 or 1. If 0 the account isn't activated and if it's 1 it's activated.

Also, I'm using phpacademy's oop Login/Register system. This is my first website using PDO and OOP so I'm not really familiar with the language.

What should I do to fix this? Anyone with some ideas?

If you guys need anything to help me just let me know.

Here's Session.php:

```
<?php
class Session {
    public static function exists($name) {
        return (isset($_SESSION[$name])) ? true : false;
    }

    public static function put($name, $value) {
        return $_SESSION[$name] = $value;
    }

    public static function get($name) {
        return $_SESSION[$name];
    }

    public static function delete($name) {
        if (self::exists($name)) {
            unset($_SESSION[$name]);
        }
    }

    public static function flash($name, $string = '') {
        if (self::exists($name)) {
            $session = self::get($name);
            self::delete($name);
            return $session;
        } else {
            self::put($name, $string);
            $session = self::get($name);
            return $session;
        }
    }
}
```

and Validate.php:

```
<?php
class Validate {
    private $_passed = false,
            $_errors = array(),
            $_db = null;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->_db = DB::getInstance();
    }

    public function check($source, $items = array()) {
        foreach($items as $item => $rules){
            $value = trim($source[$item]);
            $alias = $item;

            foreach($rules as $rule => $rule_value) {
                if(isset($rules['alias'])){
                    $alias = $rules['alias'];
                }

                $alias = escape(ucfirst($alias));

                if($rule === 'required' && empty($value)) {
                    $this->addError($alias.' is required.');
                } else if(!empty($value)) {
                    switch($rule) {
                        case 'min':
                            if(strlen($value) < $rule_value) {
                                $this->addError($alias." must be a minimum of {$rule_value} characters.");
                            }
                        break;
                        case 'max':
                            if(strlen($value) > $rule_value) {
                                $this->addError($alias." can only be a maximum of {$rule_value} characters.");
                            }
                        break;
                        case 'matches':
                            if($value != $source[$rule_value]) {
                                $this->addError(ucfirst($rule_value).' must match '.strtolower($alias).'.');
                            }
                        break;
                        case 'unique':
                            $check = $this->_db->get($rule_value, array($item, '=', $value));
                            if($check->count()) {
                                $this->addError($alias.' has already been taken.');
                            }
                        break;
                        case 'first_not_numeric':
                            if (is_numeric($value[0])) {
                                $this->addError($alias.' cannot begin with a number.');
                            }
                        break;
                        case 'email';
                            if(filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false){
                                $this->addError("Email not valid");
                            }
                        break;
                        case 'email_exists';
                            if($users->email_exists($_POST['email']) === true) {
                                $this->addError("Email already exists!");
                            }
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if(empty($this->_errors)) {
            $this->_passed = true;
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function addError($error) {
        $this->_errors[] = $error;
    }

    public function errors() {
        return $this->_errors;
    }
    public function passed() {
        return $this->_passed;
    }
}
```

login.php:

```
<?php
require_once 'core/init.php';

$user = new User();
if ($user->isLoggedIn()) {
    Redirect::to('index.php');
}
?>

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Log in</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/global.css">
    <script src="js/jQuery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>  
    <input type="checkbox" id="sidebartoggler">
    <input type="checkbox" id="profiletoggler">

    <div class="page-wrap">

        <?php require_once 'includes/header.php'; ?>
        <?php require_once 'includes/navbar.php'; ?>
        <?php require_once 'includes/profilebar.php'; ?>

        <div class="page-content">
            <form action="" method="post">
                <h1>Log in</h1>
                <div class="inset">
                <?php
                if (input::exists()) {
                    if (Token::check(Input::get('token'))) {

                        $validate = new Validate();
                        $validation = $validate->check($_POST, array(
                            'username' => array(
                                'required' => true,
                                'alias' => 'Username'
                            ),
                            'password' => array(
                                'required' => true,
                                'alias' => 'Password'
                            )
                        ));

                        if ($validation->passed()) {
                            $user = new User();

                            $remember = (Input::get('remember') === 'on') ? true : false;
                            $login = $user->login(Input::get('username'), Input::get('password'), $remember);

                            if ($login) {
                                Redirect::to('index.php');
                            } else {
                                foreach ($validation->errors() as $error) {
                                    echo '<i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;', $error, '<br>';
                                    echo '<br />';
                                    //echo '<pre>', print_r($validation->errors()), '</pre>';
                                }
                            }

                        } else {
                            foreach ($validation->errors() as $error) {
                                echo '<i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;', $error, '<br>';
                                echo '<br />';
                                //echo '<pre>', print_r($validation->errors()), '</pre>';
                            }
                        } 

                    }
                }

                if(Session::exists('login')) {
                    echo '<p><i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;' . Session::flash('login') . '</p><br />';
                }
                ?>
                <p>
                    <label for="username">USERNAME</label>
                    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="<?php echo escape(Input::get('username')); ?>">
                </p>
                    <!--<?php
                    /*if(isset($validation) && !$validation->passed()){
                        foreach($validation->errors() as $error){
                            if ($error->alias = 'Username') {
                                echo '<i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;', $error, '<br>';
                                echo '<br />';
                            }
                        }
                    }*/
                    ?>-->
                <p>
                    <label for="password">PASSWORD</label>
                    <input type="password" name="password" id="password">
                </p>
                <p>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="remember" id="remember">
                    <label for="remember">Remember me for 1 month</label>
                </p>
                </div>

                <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo Token::generate(); ?>">
                <p class="p-container">
                    <span>Forgot password?</span>
                    <input type="submit" name="go" id="go" value="Log in">
                </p>
            </form>
        </div>
        <?php require_once 'includes/footer.php'; ?>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Above the login class I have this:

```
private $_db,
        $_data,
        $_sessionName,
        $_cookieName,
        $_isLoggedIn;
```

And underneath the login class I have this:

```
public function data() {
    return $this->_data;
}

public function isLoggedIn() {
    return $this->_isLoggedIn;
}
```

Thanks in advance,

Busarna

Comment: `if ($this->data()->activated = 1) {` That should be `==` instead of `=`.

Comment: @PatrickQ As mentioned in the question I tried that as well with no luck

Comment: That doesn't mean that you change it to something that is most definitely not going to work.

Comment: what does this line do `Session::put($this->_sessionName, $this->data()->id);` by the way it is hard to help you because you dont show your custom classes and functions. who knows how it works behind the scenes

Comment: @meda I added Session.php and Validate.php. Just let me know if anything else is needed.

Comment: yes it is better now, it is still missing the part with the function `data()` sorry to be a pain.

Comment: I've added that as well now @meda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I may be wrong, but ENUM fields are treated as strings. You may want to wrap the `$this->data()->activated` code with `intval()`, to typecast it as the integer you're trying to strict check it against.

```
if (1 === intval($this->data()->activated)) { ... }
```

In your code: `$this->data()->activated = 1` is a bug - you're trying to do an assignment.

And finally, you need to move `return true;` to after the `if ($remember) { ... }` block. You were always returning a true statement, even when you were encountering the error condition of not being activated.

---

After you posted the login.php file, I noticed that you are creating a new `$validate` variable inside the `$user->login` method, but are not returning it to be used in the login.php script. Try removing the line:

```
$validate = new Validate();
```

from the login function (**not** the login.php file), and when you call the $user->login function, pass the $validate variable as a reference.

```
public function login($username = null, $password = null, $remember = false, &$validate = null) { ... }
```

call it in login.php as such:

```
$login = $user->login(Input::get('username'), Input::get('password'), $remember, $validate);
```

Comment: I did what you said @jsickles and now when I press log in the password field gets empty and nothing more happen when I try to log in

Comment: I don't know the workings of `phpacademy`, but it sounds like you're not handling errors that are being returned, perhaps?

Comment: I added login.php as well. Now you can see every file needed to see how the error handling is done. Hope that help you to help me @jsickles ;)

Comment: `$login = $user->login(Input::get('username'), Input::get('password'), $remember);` <-- you have no way of returning the `$validate` variable you set inside the login script. I'm modifying my answer to include this change.

Comment: Please select my answer as the correct one. You should be able to click the checkmark next to it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I dont really find this function clean, if I were you I would split into another function just to check if user is actif,and only run the login process once you are sure it is active.

**function**

```
public function user_is_active($username, $password){
    $is_active = ($this->data()->activated === 1);
    return $is_active;
}
```

And check the return of the function to add the errors when they return false

```
$validate = new Validate(); 
$user_is_found = $this->find($username);
if(!$user_is_found){
    $validate->addError('username not found');
}else{
    $is_active = user_is_active($username);
    if(!$is_active){
        $validate->addError('user is not active');
    }else{
        $isLoggedIn = login($username, $password, true);
        if(!$isLoggedIn){
            $validate->addError('password is not valid');
        }else{
            //login succesful redirect here
        }
    }
}
```

So just manage to return true or false in the login logic.

finally check if any errors:

```
$errors = $validate->errors();
if(count($errors)>0){
     var_dump($errors);
}
```

Comment: I did that but there's one problem. When I log in with details I get this: Notice: Undefined variable: user_is_active in D:\Program\xampp\htdocs\website\classes\User.php on line 67

Fatal error: Function name must be a string in D:\Program\xampp\htdocs\website\classes\User.php on line 67. If I don't fill everything in it works though. Then I get this: array(2) { [0]=> string(21) "Username is required." [1]=> string(21) "Password is required." } @meda do you know how to fix this? Thanks in advance

Comment: sorry I had a typo its `user_is_active($username);` without the dollar signs, Im giving you pointers this code is not tested @Busarna4

Comment: I changed that and that works, but now I get this: Warning: Missing argument 2 for User::user_is_active(), called in D:\Program\xampp\htdocs\website\classes\User.php on line 67 and defined in D:\Program\xampp\htdocs\website\classes\User.php on line 144. I know why, the user_is_active($username, $password) requires both username and password, but I only give it the username: $is_active = $this->user_is_active($username);. Should I add the password to it or should I remove the password here: user_is_active($username, $password)? @meda

Comment: Also, when I type a username that doesn't exist I have the same problem as before, the password field gets empty and nothing more happen @meda

Comment: The answer from jsickles worked. However, do you know how to make this class better? His answer is changes on my original login function, but you said earlier that that function wasn't clean. @meda

Comment: Damn that was another typo please remove the password argument

Comment: Okay, but now I get this if I try to log in: Fatal error: Call to undefined function login() in D:\Program\xampp\htdocs\website\classes\User.php on line 70. Should I change this: $isLoggedIn = login($username, $password, true); if(!$isLoggedIn){ to: if ($this->data()->password === Hash::make($password, $this->data()->salt)) {, should I create a new function for that or is there something else? @meda

Comment: Yes do that or just call it the same way you are currently doing it. Again i did  not test

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56713/discussion-between-meda-and-busarna4).

Answer (score 0):

Use

`if ($this->data()->activated == 1) {`

and Change this ...

```
                 }

            } else {
                $validate->addError('You need to activate your account before you login!');
            }

            return true;
```

To this ...

```
                 }
                 return true;
            } else {
                $validate->addError('You need to activate your account before you login!');
            }
```

Comment: I did what you said @cmorrissey and now when I press log in the password field gets empty and nothing more happen when I try to log in